# How to include PDF in Sphinx documentation?

Tags: python, pdf, python-sphinx

I have a PDF that has some in depth explanation for an example in the Sphinx documentation for a package I have. Is there a way to easily include the PDF in my project (and have it copy over when I build the docs)? I tried linking to it with :doc: but this did not copy it over.

Comment: Sometimes it's preferable to view PDFs in the browser. The answer to [a similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38613647/sphinx-linking-to-embedded-binary-files-pdfs) makes that possible.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use the [:download:](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/markup/inline.html#role-download) text role to bring in an arbitrary additional file. So in your case you might do something like this:

```
For an in-depth explanation, please see :download:`A Detailed Example <some_extra_file.pdf>`.
```

Comment: New link for the download directive: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html#role-download