# Sphinx directive to open a PDF in the browser

Tags: pdf, python-sphinx

tl;dr How can I make a PDF in the Sphinx html output open directly in the browser (or externally)? I want to click on the link and the PDF just opens.

I am currently trying to make sphinx create a link that opens a PDF file in the browser instead of downloading it. So far I only found the download directive, which is useful but I do not want to download those files as they are already available locally. 
If there is no default way is there any way to extend Sphinx to achieve this behaviour?

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/38613647/407651

Comment: Thanks, it is not exactely what i was searching for but it should do. As mentioned there it  appears there is no other solution so far..